# Gotta Tag 'em All

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Whilst perusing through the tags, I noticed there is one for [pokemon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon).  Do we really need one specific to this or can these be removed or changed to [video-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games)?

Comment: Note that Pokémon could be a video game, movie, TV show, or card game.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain True, it could even be replaced with `trivia` instead.  The tag just seems oddly specific, like if we had an `american-history` tag or `hockey` tag.

Comment: I suppose the reason it exists is because we've had a number of "guess the pokémon" puzzles.  Without the tag, you would have to explicitly state that the solution to the puzzle is a pokémon.  With the tag, you can just tag it and it should be obvious to people.  But I'll let others weigh in on whether it should be kept.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]: Deusovi and I have got rid of the Pokemon tag from all the questions which had it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## No we do not need the tag

While [pokemon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon) is quite a broad subject, it is still too specific

Pokemon can relate to many things, but can be replaced for each one:

- [Pokemon video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_(video_game_series)) replaced with [video-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games)
- [Pokemon movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_films) replaced with [movies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies)
- [Pokemon TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_(anime)) replaced with [tv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv)
- [Pokemon Card Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Trading_Card_Game) replaced with [cards](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cards)
- [Pokemon Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Go) replaced with [video-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games)  (Or as @AlwaysConfused points out: maybe [geography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography) or [geocaching](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geocaching))

And if the question wants to *specifically* mention pokemon, then it can say so in the title or in the question...

**We shouldn't have to rely on the tags to solve the puzzle**

If we do then the question is unclear...

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]: Deusovi and I have got rid of the Pokemon tag from all the questions which had it.

Comment: The tag wasn't very effective.

Comment: Maybe [Geography](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/geography/info)  or [Geocaching](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/geocaching/info) could be applied to include Pokemon "Go" ?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused good point I'll add that

Comment: According to the tag wikis, maybe Geocaching is better tag (than geography) to describe pokemon Go?